# How Do I Get Android Crash Logs?

Tags: android, logcat

I have one application installed in my LG Optimus 2X , sometimes it get crashed but I don't know what's the reasion for the crash. I want **LogCat** to be shown in my computer when I connect my device to my computer. Can you, please, tell me how to do this?

Comment: what do you use for developing? eclipse?

Comment: use [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) for getting crash reports of appliction

Comment: I have used App [alogcate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5qdGIuYWxvZ2NhdCJd) for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can a.) install the free app "Android System Info". With that app you can save the device LogCat to your SD card or b.) install the Android SDK and use the ADB to fetch the LogCat from the device.

Answer (score 1):

You can read log programmatically.

If you wish you can read them and store them as a textfile or in a database that you can read later when get connected.

[Code to read Logs](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/reading-logs-programatically) dont forget to add permission of `android.permission.READ_LOGS`

But still I believe the Comment I have made is more easier way.

Answer (score 1):

While your device is connected, just use "adb logcat" command (adb command is inside android-sdk-mac_x86/platform-tools folder) and then start the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/) for example with [ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) installed you will have a perspective called [DDMS](http://d339vfjsz5zott.cloudfront.net/1_IntroductionToAndroid/eclipse_debugging_android_development.jpg) which will show you your device and can show the logCat for that device